# OnResume not called when hitting back button from Tab Host

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-tabhost, onresume

I'm running into a pesky issue. I have **two tab hosts** ... **tab host A** and **tab host B**. Each tab host has three tabs (let's call them A1, B1, A2, B2, etc). **Tab host B is launched from Activity A2**. Anyway, here is my problem:

When I'm in one of the tabs of tab host B and I navigate back to Activity A2 using the built in back button, `onResume` does not get called. I don't understand why this is the case ... I read the article on the Activity Lifecycle and it seems to me that as soon as Tab host B launches that Activity A2's onStop method should have been called ... and that as soon as I navigate back to it with the back button that A2's onStart and onResume methods should have been called. The only thing that I can think of is that maybe Tab Host A's `onResume` is being called instead of Activty A2's on resume. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code I am using to kick of A2 from Tab Host A:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FiltersActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("filters").setIndicator("Filters",
       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_filters)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: please paste your code for in which you are navigating from one activity to another is it startActivityforresult

Comment: do you mean the code from Activity A2 which launches the Tab Host B? Or are you referring to something else? Btw thank you for the very quick reply :)

Comment: you wrote that you are going to activity A2 You must used some intent to initiate the activity A2 i wanted that code

Comment: Are you starting new activities for all of the different tabs?

Comment: intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FiltersActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("filters").setIndicator("Filters",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_filters))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

Comment: I'm sorry that the formatting is poor ... I wasn't able to get it to look nicer. And Barak, I am indeed starting new activities for each of the different tabs.

Comment: Just add the code to your original post as an edit... not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The developer page´s comment inherit´s the answer

```
 // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
```

The activity is wrapped in your tab specification and it´s lifecycle is related to the specification now.

What you might wanna do is provide your own method you call when you switch to a tab and call it.

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTab(resumeTab);
Activity filtersActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();
filtersActivity.yourMethod();
```

Comment: The `getCurrentActivity()` method doesn't seem to exist